# Xamarin.iOS - Application Name 'App.exe' conflicts with another user assembly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Has anyone ever seen this issue before. Looks to be MTouch related but I really don't know where to go from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short:** Rename `App.exe` to something else, like `MyApp.exe`

**Why?** You likely have an assembly named `App.dll`. A fully qualified assembly name does not contain the file type (.dll or .exe) so having `App.exe` cause a conflict - since both would be referred as `App`.

Comment: How do I rename it? I went and renamed it in the file system but it seems like Visual Studio just re-created the old file as soon as it started up.

Comment: The filename is based on the compiler output. VS has options to let you change the output assembly name (without changing the project name).

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion which might help you solve this problem:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92773/the-root-assembly-conflicts-with-another-assembly?

I had the same problem and updating Xamarin Forms in Windows (from VS 2015 Tools / Options / Xamarin / Others), Mac (from Xamarin Studio) and updating the XamarinForms NuGet package in the failing solution solved my problem.